# Unknown column in 'on clause' with FULL JOIN MySQL keyword

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with FULL JOIN keyword used in MySQL

```
SELECT Name,Surname,Notes.Payment FROM Persons FULL JOIN Notes ON  Persons.id=Notes.P_Id
```

it give me this error :

```
Unknown column 'Persons.id' in 'on clause'
```

but if I call with LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN, the results appear properly.

What is the problem with FULL JOIN ?

Thank you

Comment: Because mysql does not have a "full" join, your query gave `Persons` an alias of `FULL`. Once you did that, only the alias `FULL` is visible as the table in the query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL does not (yet) support `FULL JOIN`.

Use something like this:

```
  SELECT Name, Surname, Notes.Payment 
  FROM Persons 
    LEFT JOIN Notes 
      ON Persons.id = Notes.P_Id
UNION ALL
  SELECT Name, Surname, Notes.Payment 
  FROM Persons 
    RIGHT JOIN Notes 
      ON Persons.id = Notes.P_Id
  WHERE Persons.id IS NULL
```

The error you get is because `FROM Persons FULL JOIN Notes ON` is parsed as:

```
FROM Persons AS FULL 
  JOIN Notes
    ON ...
```

Comment: I didn't know that MySQL doesn't support that keyword. Thank you ypercube

Comment: use "union" without "where Person.id is NULL" because union by default remove the duplicate values.

Comment: @OmarAl-Howeiti we could use `UNION` yes. But I'd expect this to be more efficient as it wouldn't require the remove-duplicates step.